# Strange HDD noise on Linux but not Windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, linux-mint

I have Windows 11 and Linux Mint dual boot on my notebook. When I use Windows, HDD (WDC WD10JPVX-22JC3T0) works without much noise (almost silently). However, when I use Linux Mint and Ubuntu, HDD makes strange noises while read and write operations.

HDD is kinda old (2013) but still OK. It passes all tests (bad block, SMART, etc.) without any error.

Since I installed Ubuntu 16.4 till now that I have Linux Mint 20.2 this noise was there on these Linux distributions. Now that I installed a SSD and moved HDD into a Caddy, the noise is heard a little louder and sometimes get annoying.

What is the cause of this noise? Is there any way to make it work silently just like Windows?

Comment: Are you using different file systems, i.e, NTSF for Windows and ext4 for Linux?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes. Windows partition on SSD and data partitions on HDD are NTFS. Linux root (on SSD) and home (on HDD) partitions are ext4.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have Linux on the outer platters. Typically - for a 2TB HDD - Windows would occupy the first 1TB and Linux the later 1TB.
The hdd has platters arranged around the center. It simply means that one of the moving parts are worn out and the seek is causing the noise.
When the seek accesses the inner platters, the noise is less and it gets worse for the outer platters.

I would get another HDD and make a quick backup. A good option would be to replace your HDD with a new one and use the old one for data storage where it will have occasional use.

Comment: Before I install the SSD, Windows was in third partition (after EFI and recovery) and Linux was in last one (actually last before 8GB SWAP partition). However, now both are on SSD and HDD only contains data. And it doesn't matter if I use the first or last partition, it makes that noise.

Comment: As I said, the noise was there since the first time I installed a Linux distribution which was Ubuntu 16.04. So HDD was just 3 years old (2013-2016) and I think HDDs are much more durable than this. My HDD is 1TB WesternDigital Blue.

Comment: If your HDD is making an audible seek noise - its on its last legs. Best get another one. You can still use it to store non-essential data.

Comment: Try this solution with **hdparm** - https://superuser.com/a/415189/923014